# Maya 2016 Python - "No module named PyQt4"

Tags: python, path, pyqt, pyqt4, maya

I'm trying to do some basic Qt4 tutorials. However when I try to import the Python QT4 module it is not found. I thought QT4 was included with the basic Maya installation? I'm on a Windows machine.

```
# Error: ImportError: file <maya console> line 1: No module named PyQt4
```

Here are all my Maya system paths:

```
C:/ProgramData/Autodesk/ApplicationPlugins/Red9StudioPack/Contents/scripts/Red9
C:/ProgramData/Autodesk/ApplicationPlugins/Red9StudioPack/Contents/scripts
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2016\bin
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2016
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2016\plug-ins\bifrost\scripts\presets
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2016\plug-ins\bifrost\scripts
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX For Autodesk Maya\2016 64bit\bin\scripts
C:\ProgramData\Autodesk\ApplicationPlugins\Red9StudioPack\Contents\scripts
C:\Users\Johnny\Documents\maya\2016\modules\SHAPES\scripts
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2016\plug-ins\fbx\scripts
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\mentalrayForMaya2016\scripts\AETemplates
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\mentalrayForMaya2016\scripts\mentalray
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\mentalrayForMaya2016\scripts\unsupported
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\mentalrayForMaya2016\scripts
C:\Program Files (x86)\ngSkinTools\Maya2016-64bit\scripts
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2016\plug-ins\substance\scripts
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2016\bin\python27.zip
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2016\Python\DLLs
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2016\Python\lib
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2016\Python\lib\plat-win
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2016\Python\lib\lib-tk
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2016\bin
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2016\Python
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2016\Python\lib\site-packages
C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2016\bin\python27.zip\lib-tk
C:/Users/Johnny/Documents/maya/2016/prefs/scripts
C:/Users/Johnny/Documents/maya/2016/scripts
C:/Users/Johnny/Documents/maya/scripts
```

Comment: You could try to download and install it from http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro

Comment: Please don't do that. Maya needs a special cut of PyQt to work with it. Also, Maya 2016 already ships with PySide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maya includes QT (the C++ version) but uses [PySide](http://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/Maya-SDK/files/GUID-3F96AF53-A47E-4351-A86A-396E7BFD6665-htm.html) instead of PyQt as the wrapper

Comment: Ah ok thank you. So I should still be able to use QT designer, correct? And instead of importing pyqt just import pyside?

Comment: That's the theory, anyway :)

Comment: Yes you ll just have to do a few things different to work with the .ui files from Qt Designer in PySide. I will post the link a bit later here.